# How to check whether group of selectbox is seleted or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following java script code......

```
         var dataString = 'CategoryId='+categoryid+"&FormatId="+formatid;

         $.ajax({
                    type:"Post",
                    url:"MyServlet",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data : dataString,
                    success: function(data){                                        
                        var type1= data.a;  
                        var type2 = data.b;
                        var type3 = data.c;
                        var type4 = data.d;
                        var type5 = data.e;
                        var type6 = data.f;

                        if(type1){
                            $('#type1id').append("<option value=0>SelectOne</option>");    
                            $.each(type1, function(i, value){
                                $('#type1id').append("<option value='"+this.Id+"'>"+this.DisplayName+"</option>");                              
                            });
                            $('#set1').show();
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#set1').hide();
                        }

                        if(type2){
                            $('#type2id').append("<option value=0>SelectOne</option>");    
                            $.each(type2, function(i, value){
                                $('#type1id').append("<option value='"+this.Id+"'>"+this.DisplayName+"</option>");                              
                            });
                            $('#set2').show();
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#set2').hide();
                        }

                        if(type3){
                            $('#type3id').append("<option value=0>SelectOne</option>");    
                            $.each(type3, function(i, value){
                                $('#type3id').append("<option value='"+this.Id+"'>"+this.DisplayName+"</option>");                              
                            });
                            $('#set3').show();
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#set3').hide();
                        }

              // etc...
              // etc...
              // till type6



                    }                       
                });
```

i have following html code......

```
          <div id="section-2" class="section-content">
            <fieldset id="set1">
              <label for="type1id">Type 1</label>
              <select id="type1id"> </select>         
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="set2">
              <label for="type2id">Type 2</label>
              <select id="type2id"> </select>         
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="set3">
              <label for="type3id">Type 3</label>
              <select id="type3id"> </select>         
            </fieldset>
          </div>

         <button disabled="disabled" type="button" id="section2-next">
             Next
         </button>
```

i am filling all selectbox dynamically using $.ajax() function by getting json response..
the number of select box displayed depends on json data for e.g if json returns 1 array then i am only showing 1 selectbox, if json returns 2 array i am showing 2 selectbox etc.... how to check whether all shown selectbox selected and then and then only enable Next button?

Comment: So, how to check if every select box has something loaded? Or if only available selects have an option selected?

Comment: Will the select boxes have a blank value? If not, they'll always have something selected. It's really impossible to answer based on what you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working example at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDBSY/)

```
// example data; feeding selects
for(var i=0; i<3;i++) {
    tmpSelect = $("select")[i];
    $(tmpSelect).append($("<option/>").text("-- Choose option --").val("0"));
    for(var y=0;y<5;y++) $(tmpSelect).append($("<option/>").text("hoho"+y).val(y+5));
}

$("#section-2 select").on('change', function() {
    var validated=false;
    $.each($("#section-2 select"), function(k,elm){
        if(this.value==0) { 
            validated=false;
            return false;
        } else { 
            validated = true;
        }
    });
    if(validated) $("#section2-next").removeAttr("disabled"); // all selectboxes is seleceted..
    else $("#section2-next").attr("disabled", "disabled");  // Not selected yet..
});
```

Edit(Update):

If you also adding your selects trought javascript then change $.on to this

```
$("#section-2").on('change', 'select', function()
```

[Live example when i feed it with selects from an js-object](http://jsfiddle.net/QGRPZ/)

Comment: thanks for ans, but i have multile selectbox currenty i have shown 3 but it changes according to servlet json response. the no of selectbox shown is not static its dynamic

Comment: I have updated my code with an example. As you see I feed it trought a object, and is totaly dynamic.

Comment: i did like this                                                     var sel = $(this);                               if(sel.is(':empty')=== false){//and added if else block here}

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DUrhn/)

This depends on the way you are filling up the options for selects. If you don't have an extra element added at top like --Select--. Then one of the options will always be selected. If you do have this then you can give this an arbitary value

```
<select class="mySelect">
 <option value="myVal"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="mySelect">
 <option value="myVal"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="mySelect">
 <option value="myVal"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button id="myButton">Next</button>
```

and then:

```
$(function(){
$(".mySelect").change(function(){
    var myVar = false;
    $(".mySelect").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "myVal"){
            myVar = true;
        }
    });
    if(!myVar){
        $("#myButton").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#myButton").hide();
    }
});
});
```